# Checar se mais abas de site X está aberta

Tags: javascript

Existe a possibilidade de checar se meu site está aberto mais de uma vez no navegador do usuário?

Meu site exige que seja usada apenas uma aba para nao ocorrer error de comunicação, por isso preciso alertar o usuário quando ele abrir mais de uma aba do meu site, existe essa possibilidade com JavaScript?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54619/discussion-on-question-by-user3163662-checar-se-mais-abas-de-site-x-esta-aberta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como sugerido nos comentários, pode-se usar *local storage*/*session storage* para fazer essa verificação. Vou dar um exemplo bem simples:

1. Verifica se existe uma contagem; se não existe, começa do `1`, caso contrário incrementa a que está lá;
2. Ouve por eventos no *storage*; se a contagem mudou, é porque tem outra página tentando alterá-la ao mesmo tempo;

   - Se a página que está tentando alterá-la "chegou primeiro" (i.e. possui uma contagem menor), então ela é quem manda. Retira-se...
   - Se a página que está tentando alterá-la "chegou depois" (i.e. possui uma contagem maior), então a página atual é quem manda. Reseta a contagem para seu próprio valor.

```js
var contagem = +localStorage.getItem("contagem"); // Antigo dono
window.addEventListener("storage", storageChanged, false);
localStorage.setItem("contagem", contagem+1); // Tenta se tornar o novo dono

function storageChanged(event) {
    if ( event.newValue <= contagem )    // Se o antigo dono ainda estiver por aí
        alert("Já tem uma aba aberta."); // Vai embora
    else                                              // Senão
        localStorage.setItem("contagem", contagem+1); // torna-se o novo dono
}
```

Se executar o código acima, não vai acontecer nada. Mas se abrir essa resposta numa nova aba e mandar executar o código, <del>o alerta será exibido</del> (Parece que não funciona no StackSnippets, o código está num `iframe` *sandboxed* que não permite `allow-same-origin`... [No jsFiddle funcionou](http://jsfiddle.net/f4u1tL4d/), entretanto...).

(**Nota:** quando uma página altera o *storage*, um evento é disparado em todas as **outras** páginas na mesma origem. A *própria página* que alterou não recebe evento algum.)

Altere a parte onde há o `alert` para fazer alguma outra coisa (tipo fechar a aba com `window.close`). Pode-se aprimorar bastante o código acima - por exemplo, fazendo com que quando a aba principal for fechada ela passe o comando para a próxima na fila (supondo que as demais permaneçam abertas, somente inativas) - mas aí já fica um pouquinho mais complexo...

Dito isso, pro seu caso particular sugiro tratar desses "erros de comunicação" em vez de exigir que somente uma aba esteja aberta - se o usuário tentar acessar sua conta em dois *browsers* diferentes, por exemplo, o que aconteceria? Melhor projetar o sistema de modo que duas abas abertas não causem problemas, nem que pra isso tenha de contar com a ajuda do servidor.